# RSyslogd is sending multiples CEF messages in the same Syslog message

Tags: rsyslog, syslog-ng, syslogd

There is a Python script sending multiple events to a remote host with Rsyslogd:

```
CEF:0|Test|SIEMintegration|1|1|Normal|0| fileId=767000670128771115
CEF:0|Test|SIEMintegration|1|1|Normal|0| fileId=766000430136104144
```

But when they reach to that remote host, those messages seem to be concatenated in the same Syslog message:

[Two CEF messages concatenated in the same Syslog message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQMBJ.png)

Would you know why it could be happening?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is that supposed to be the entire message? The screenshot implies a _significantly_ larger message.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, I have shortened the messages because they are extremely long, especially considering that they can be several CEF concatenated.  But in  the source log, there is one CEF message per line exactly, that was the idea that I was trying to summarize.

Comment: I think you've run into a very subtle bug in Python. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40041697/1068283) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52950147/1068283) for possible workarounds.